# ScrollTop really jerky in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrollto, scrolltop, parallax

I'm using the scrollTop function to create a parallax scrolling website, binding the scrollTop function to different anchors throughout my website.

The problem I'm having is that the scrolling becomes really choppy/jerky in Chrome, but somehow its fine in Firefox.

My code is as follows:

```
 $('.recipes').click(function(){
 $('html,body').animate({
 scrollTop: $(".main1").offset().top
 }, 1500);
 });

 $('.cooking').click(function(){
 $('html,body').animate({
 scrollTop: $(".main2").offset().top
 }, 1500);
 });
```

Is there possibly an alternate way to do this so the website scroll isn't as jerky? maybe an easing function I can add?

- EDIT-

If I remove the following function, the jerkyness seems to go away, is there something wrong with the code or possibly a different way to write it?

```
var startY = $('#container').position().top + $('#container').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
checkY();
});

function checkY(){
if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
    $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeIn(600);
}else{
    $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeOut(600);
}
}

checkY();
```

SECOND EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.recipes').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('.main1', 1500)
 });

$('.cooking').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('.main2', 1500)
});

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $('#backToTop, #navigation').show();
        } else {
            $('#backToTop, #navigation').hide();
        }
    });
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Why are using named functions there?

Comment: not sure, I got this format from someone else, I removed the names. It now goes as follows :

$('.recipes').click(function(){
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $(".main1").offset().top
}, 1500);
});

$('.cooking').click(function(){
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $(".main2").offset().top
}, 1500);
});

but the jerky/choppyness is still happening

Comment: Your fade functions are triggered every time you scroll, so no wonder it bogs down and gets choppy.  Only trigger the fade after the scrolling stops.  See my answer.

Comment: Please append your original question with any edits.  Replacing your old question with a new one, renders the old answer totally meaningless and leads to total confusion for the reader.  I'm rolling it back.  Also, you need to explain what you want your page to do... we also can't see your HTML so that makes answering it with something precise, quite impossible.

Comment: Where is your HTML?  Where is your functional description?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is once the user scrolls more than 600 pixels, the div navigation and backToTop fade in, the problem is (window).scroll seems to be triggering it everytime the user scrolls, which causes the scroll to be jerky.

Comment: You keep referring to things as if we can see your page or your HTML.  The description needs to be part of the question and if you expect detailed help you need to provide such basic details as **the relevant HTML** and perhaps a demo on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to an alternative approach, using a plugin, [jQuery scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) has always been very smooth when I have used it.

This would let you do

```
$('.recipes').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('.main1', 1500);
});
```

Comment: It seems to act the same way as scrollTop, with a jerky scroll. 

I'm assuming my problem might be coming from my css styles - check my edits to see my css.

Thank you for the suggestions though!

Comment: I removed this function which made 2 of my elements fade in, once scrolled halfway through the first page, and the jerkyness went away,

maybe there is something wrong with my code which is causing it to be choppy. - I added it to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing your fade function on [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/), which is fired every time the page scrolls a tiny bit, do it on the [`.animate()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), which is only triggered once when the scrolling is complete.

```
$('.recipes').click(function(){
     var startY = $('#container').position().top + $('#container').outerHeight();
     $('html,body').animate(
          { scrollTop: $(".main1").offset().top },
          1500,
          function() {
             checkY(startY);
          } 
     );
});

$('.cooking').click(function(){
     var startY = $('#container').position().top + $('#container').outerHeight();
     $('html,body').animate(
         { scrollTop: $(".main2").offset().top },
         1500,
         function(){
             checkY(startY);
         }
     );
});
```

And the OP's original `checkY()` function:

```
function checkY(i) {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > i ) {
        $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeIn(600);
    } else {
        $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeOut(600);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I do this using 

$('.recipes').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('.main1', 1500);
});

$('.cooking').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('.main2', 1500);
});

and what should my checkY functions look like?

Comment: `checkY()` is just your existing `checkY()` function (see your edit on your question).  I'm just suggesting you call it from a different place.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this, but I added your original code to my answer.

Comment: that seems to be fixing it, but my fadeOut functions doesn't seem to be working anymore.

also I think the choppyness might be a result of my #navigation having a height of 100%

Comment: @MaximSiebert:  Again, I can't see your HTML, nor do I have any idea what final functionality we're trying to achieve here; your question only asks about animation choppiness.  I merely moved your fade function to reduce the load.

Comment: @MaximSiebert:  I don't even know how the `startY` variable is supposed to work.  Does is only get constructed on page load, or every time something else happens?  So much lacking information.  _However, I think I've provided more than enough detail about how you can leverage the callback function to do whatever you need._

Comment: @MaximSiebert, After spending my time trying to help you, the very least you could do is respond to my request for more information in order to get to a solution.  Ignoring my reasonable request and opening another [similarly vague question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224207/alternative-to-window-scroll) is not the proper way to use this site.

Comment: I am simply not sure what you are asking me. I will edit my original post to the code I now have.

Comment: @MaximSiebert, I'm asking you to explain yourself.  What do you want this to do?  If the code I posted doesn't work, it's because I have no idea what you really want it to do.

Comment: @MaximSiebert, You have yet to give any functional description or provide your HTML.

Comment: @Sparky is this the code to trigger a function after scrolling? $('html,body').animate(function (){ Do Something... });

Comment: @VIDesignz, that's the `scrollTop` code he originally posted that occurs on some sort of `click`.  I proposed that the `animate()` callback be used to trigger his fade effects instead of `scroll()` event.  I never saw his HTML or a functional description so I don't even know why he's having a problem now.  At least with a jsfiddle demo, we'd have something concrete to see.

Comment: @Sparky OOhhh, I get it...you just changed how it was triggered. Makes sense.  With that being said, is there a way to detect when the user stops scrolling?

Comment: @VIDesignz, until the OP provides HTML, a description and a jsFiddle or other demo page, we don't even know if that's what we really need to do.

Comment: @Sparky Your answer is spot on if he only wanted to trigger the fade in when the user clicked to go to a certain section of the page, I take it he wants it to check scrolltop whether its from a click or scrolling.

Comment: @VIDesignz, at this point, I'm going to stop commenting until a concise description including HTML and demo are provided.  We should not, and would not, be filling comments with this chatter, if the OP did his job.